# adding to a string based on the number of characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

the problem says to print "that's a really really ... big number" with one "really" for every extra digit that the number has (so 15 would be "that's a really big number", 150 would be "that's a really really big number", 1500 would be "that's a really really really big number", and so on.)

the input is an integer, and the only requirements listed are that the code should run correctly with any integer, should use a while loop to keep dividing the number by 10 and should use += to add onto the end of a string

```
x = input(("input an integer: "))
count = len(x)
y = int(x / 10)
countx = count - 1
print("that's a " + count("really") + " big number")
```

i don't really know what i did, but i can tell it's not correct

Comment: Is an extra digit considered a 0?

Comment: `count` is a number. It's not clear what you intend by calling it like a function with `count("really")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Uses while loop to divide number by 10 and += to add onto the string. You will need to take a string variable and then append to it as count increases. Loop will run until number >= 10 as conditions you mentioned.

```
x = int(input(("input an integer: ")))
str=""
while x>=10:
    x=x//10
    str+="really "
print("that's a " + str + "big number")
```

Comment: @Mark yeah no use of count=0. I forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Added the while loop as you stated in your question

```
strVar = ""
y = 0
length = 0
cnt = 0
finished = False
num = input("Type a number: ")

while not finished:
    y = int(num)//10
    length = int(len(str(y)))
    if length <= cnt:
        finished = True
    else:
        strVar += " really"

    cnt += 1
    
print("That's a" + strVar + " big number!")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
x = int(input("enter an integer"))
print("that's a " + 'really '*(len(str(x))-1) + " big number")
```

If you want to correct your function use this

```
x = input(("input an integer: "))
count = len(x)
y = int(x) / 10
countx = count - 1
print("that's a " + countx*" really" + " big number")
```

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try. It finds how many trailing zeroes there are in a given number and based on that creates a certain amount of `really's`.

```
x = input(("input an integer: "))
count = int(len(x) - len(x.rstrip('0')))
if count == 0:count = 1
really = "really "*count
print(f"that's a {really} big number")
```

Comment: `should use a while loop to keep dividing the number by 10 and should use += to add onto the end of a string`

Comment: It's an *assignment*

Comment: If you have a better idea, you create an answer.

Comment: Also says `15 would be "that's a really big number"`, your code gives `that's a  big number` for `15`.